# how can i create labels for LSTM

Tags: keras

i am working on video classification problem so  i converted my videos into images every video converted to 7 images and then path them to vgg16 to extract features from those images and then use LSTM to learn the sequence of images for every video

when i feed the vgg16 results to my LSTM i need to give every 7 image one label because i am dealing with sequence so i need to create this lables by my self so how can i create  labels in python

by the way its binary classification problem